# How to display place name in google map into website?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I try to display a name on the google map in [my website](http://new.travelenter.com/home/contact) .I use  blow code and now shown map of my position currently but name of this position don't display .
How to fix this?

```
     <!-- Google Map Api -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=fa"></script>
<script src="/Content/Travelo/js/gmap3.js"></script>
     $(".travelo-google-map").gmap3({
            map: {
                options: {
                    center: [35.7277533, 51.3037064],
                    zoom: 12
                }
            },
            marker: {
                values: [
                    { latLng: [35.7277533, 51.3037064], data: "آداک سفر پایا" }

                ],
                options: {
                    draggable: false
                },
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need  a map Label you can use  an extension library called google-maps utility libraries v3 map label ..

You can find the code at : https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

add this library to your

```
               aMapLabel = new MapLabel({
                text: 'Your Text',
                position: mapLabelCenter,
                strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',       
                fontColor: '#FFFFFF',             
                map: map,
                fontSize: 24,
                strokeWeight: 0,   
                align: 'left'
            });

            marker.bindTo('map', aMapLabel);
            marker.bindTo('position', aMapLabel);
```